# Gitkraken shows `error matching pattern` when trying to take any action

Tags: git, gitkraken

GitKraken shows the following error when I try to take any action, and it only shows that for one of my repositories.

```py
[Thu Jul 18 2019 17:58:25 GMT+0300 (Arabian Standard Time)] Pull Failed: error matching pattern
[Thu Jul 18 2019 18:05:32 GMT+0300 (Arabian Standard Time)] Pull Failed: error matching pattern
[Thu Jul 18 2019 19:08:05 GMT+0300 (Arabian Standard Time)] Pull Failed: error matching pattern
[Thu Jul 18 2019 19:08:09 GMT+0300 (Arabian Standard Time)] Checkout Failed: error matching pattern
[Thu Jul 18 2019 22:02:51 GMT+0300 (Arabian Standard Time)] Checkout Failed: error matching pattern
[Thu Jul 18 2019 22:03:04 GMT+0300 (Arabian Standard Time)] Checkout Failed: error matching pattern
```

[image: error matching pattern]

I tried removing the repo and cloning it again but no luck

PS: everything works when I try to use the CLI!

Comment: Does the name of your repo contain non-latin characters?

Comment: no, but it turned out to be a known issue according to https://gitkraken.slack.com/archives/C2DB7B0JG/p1563438801386200

Comment: I am having the same problem after updating to v6.01. I am unable to use GK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue that was introduced in v6.0.1, it happens when you are using a .gitignore file with a negation `!` rule in it. The GitKraken team is currently investigating a fix for an upcoming release.

In the meantime, you can comment out any negation rules, or you can use the prior version of GitKraken, which should be accessible under C:\Users{USER}\AppData\Local\gitkraken\app-6.0.0.